# How can I update the DolphinDB license online within a cluster?

Tags: database, high-availability, dolphindb

The current cluster is a high availability cluster and the node alias are

```
`controller1`controller2`controller3`agent1`agent2`agent3`NODE1`NODE2`NODE3.
```

How can I efficiently update licenses on all nodes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pnodeRun()` function to the `updateLicense` function on all data nodes in the cluster. Here is an example:

```
pnodeRun(updateLicense(), `controller1`controller2`controller3`aget1`agent2`agent3`NODE1`NODE`NODE3)
```